# What DB indexes would be best where we have a combination of AND & OR conditions in where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, database-indexes

In my multi-tenant database, I have a table called 'Group_Table'. It has the following structure,

| Group_id | Group_Name | Group_Owner_Id | Customer_Id | Privacy_Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Group 1 | 123421 | customerA | 1 |
| 2 | Group 2 | 123421 | customerA | 2 |
| 3 | Group 3 | 232441 | customerB | 1 |

where,

- **Group_Owner_Id** is a long field representing the owning user of the group
- **Customer_Id** is the string-based id of the customer to whom the group belongs
- **Privacy_Level** is an enum with possible values (1,2,3)

Now, I have the following query

```
select * 
from group_table  
where customer_id = ? 
and (group_owner_id = ? OR privacy_level = ?)
```

I want to understand how can I best create index on this table to make this query efficient? The thing confusing me is how would indexes work for the OR condition?

Answer (score 2):

Under many circumstances, a simple index on `(customer_id, group_owner_id, privacy_level)` may be sufficient.  This needs to scan the index rows for a given customer, but the other values are there.

MySQL does now support index merge optimization.  This would allow the use of two separate indexes on `(customer_id, group_owner_id)` and `(customer_id, privacy_level)`.  It might require rewriting the query as:

```
where (customer_id = ? and group_owner_id = ?) or
      (customer_id = ? and privacy_level = ?)
```

This can also be emulated using `union all`:

```
select * 
from group_table  
where customer_id = :1 and group_owner_id = :2 
union all
select * 
from group_table  
where customer_id = :1 and  privacy_level = :3 and group_owner_id <> :2
```

The second condition can be made `NULL`-safe using:

```
where customer_id = :1 and  privacy_level = :3 and
      not (group_owner_id <=> :2)
```

Note that I named the parameters so it is clear what refers to what.

Comment: Why can't this be emulated simply by, 

select * from group_table
where customer_id = :1 and group_owner_id = :2 
union
select * from group_table
where customer_id = :1 and privacy_level = :3

Comment: @MurtazaHasan . . . (1) That would remove duplicates in the table if there are any, so it is not equivalent.  (2) That would incur overhead for `union` which is unnecessary.